# Filter not working with options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to translate the option items with custom filter based on Angular 1.4.8

I created a simple one to test if any item can append the string  "123"

```
app.filter('mytranslation', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return function(t_str) {
    return t_str + "123";
  };
}]);
```

However, I got this anbiguous exception,

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Filter

And other tutorials about NG filter are not working as well.

- [AngularJS : ng-repeat filter when value is greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081004/angularjs-ng-repeat-filter-when-value-is-greater-than)
- [How can I add internationalization to a select drop down with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083476/how-can-i-add-internationalization-to-a-select-drop-down-with-angularjs)

## both haml code not work too

```
%select{"ng-options" => "item.id as item.from for item in routes | mytranslation ", "ng-model"=>"selected"}
%select{"ng-options" => "item.id as (item.from | mytranslation ) for item in routes  ", "ng-model"=>"selected"}
```

## Exception on console

```
    Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=mytranslationFilterProvider%20%3C-%20mytranslationFilter
        at Error (native)
        at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.min-b5b8b02773bd468b763522da33293b86.js?body=1:7:416
        at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.min-b5b8b02773bd468b763522da33293b86.js?body=1:42:121
        at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.min-b5b8b02773bd468b763522da33293b86.js?body=1:40:92)
        at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.min-b5b8b02773bd468b763522da33293b86.js?body=1:42:195
        at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.min-b5b8b02773bd468b763522da33293b86.js?body=1:40:92)
        at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.min-b5b8b02773bd468b763522da33293b86.js?body=1:150:129
        at W (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.min-b5b8b02773bd468b763522da33293b86.js?body=1:112:209)
        at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.min-b5b8b02773bd468b763522da33293b86.js?body=1:110:334
        at n (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.min-b5b8b02773bd468b763522da33293b86.js?body=1:8:333) <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.id as item.from for item in routes | mytranslation " class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
```

## Update Version 2

## routes (array of object)

```
[
{
from: "BANGKOK",
to: [
"KAOHSIUNG",
"TAIPEI",
"OSAKA",
"TOKYO",
"SINGAPORE"
]
},
{
from: "CHIANGMAI",
to: [
"TAIPEI"
]
},
]
```

## the fileter was not triggered

```
app.filter('mytranslation', function(data){
    return data + "123";
});
```

## Generated HTML (Not as my expectation)

```
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.id as item.from for item in routes | filter:mytranslation" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
        <option label="BANGKOK" value="undefined:undefined">BANGKOK</option>
        .....
        <option label="CHIANGMAI" value="undefined:undefined">CHIANGMAI</option>
```

## Expectation result should be

```
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.id as item.from for item in routes | filter:mytranslation" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
        <option label="BANGKOK" value="BANGKOK">BANGKOK123</option>
        .....
        <option label="CHIANGMAI" value="CHIANGMAI">CHIANGMAI123</option>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this line `item.id as item.from for item in routes | mytranslation` should be cahnged to `item.id as item.from for item in routes | filter:mytranslation`

Comment: First of all why you injecting $rootScope is not using it?

Comment: @AlonEitan pls see the  Update Version 2, it still not works, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Your don't need the specify `filter:` in the html. Just specify the filter name(`mytranslation`) there. Like this

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.id as (item.from | mytranslation) for item in routes" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></select>
```

And your filter should be like this in JS

```
app.filter('mytranslation', function(){
    return function(data){
        return data + "123";
    }
});
```

Created a working JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WfuAh/151/

Comment: why this is wrong ? ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
i think this is for minification ?

Comment: @DivakarDass pls see the  Update Version 2, it still not works, thank you

Comment: @newBike Just updated my answer with a working JSFiddle.

Comment: thanks it works, i also notified the buggy point, however the exception it's difficult to debug

Answer (score 0):

## invalid syntax version

```
app.filter('mytranslation', function(data){
    return data + "123";
});
```

## valid version

```
app.filter('mytranslation', function(){
  return function(data){
    return data + "123";
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd say, you should have propose edit for an answer, instead of adding your own..